# Degree $n$ homogenous polynomials and canonical forms

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations

Let $x$ be a vector in $R^{d}$. Let $p(x)$ be a homogeneous quadratic polynomial. Then there is a matrix $A$ such that $p(x) = \langle x, A x \rangle$

If $p$ has degree $k$, is there a k-linear object $B$ such that we can write $p(x)=B(x)$?

Comment: Of course, there is a tensor $B$, such that $p(x) =B(x, x, \ldots, x) $.

Comment: Is this obvious? Do you have a reference?

Comment: Yes, the corresponding object is a symmetric tensor of rank $k$ called the polarization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_of_an_algebraic_form